# Effects vs Behaviors vs Renderers

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm newbie in Xamarin forms. In xamarin documentation, it seems all effects, behaviors and Renderers give same functionality of modifying native controls. please brief me when exactly we can use each of them to achieve different functionality

Comment: Please add source code what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEHAVIOR: Behaviors allow you to enhance the functionality of a Xamarin Forms control without sub classing. Using the Behaviors property you can add behaviors that attached to the Control and can execute code when events of that control are raised. don't need a separate implementation for each platform

EFFECTS: use only when you need a small styling change for any control. Effects need a seperate implementation for each platform.

RENDERER: if you want a customized control for your project create a renderer with native implementation. Renderer need to implemented for each platform